# The absolute position element's margin have no effect if it is in another absolute position element?

Tags: css, margin, css-position

I have two div like:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

then I give them style like:

```
    .outer{ background:yellow; position:absolute; width:80%; height:80px; margin:0 10%;}
    .inner{ background:red; position:absolute; margin:0 11px; width:100%; height:80px;}
```

I want the "inner"  in "outer" ,as well the left and right have both 11px space,but it can't be achieve,only the left have the 11px gap,the "inner" seems always have the same length as the father's length

Then I think maybe setting the outer padding with 11px will be work.However ,it still doesn't work……

Why this happened?So how can I solve this problem?Is that possible with the effect?

[Here is the only case](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/jsdNh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins will add up to the width which is already stretched to the outer DIV by (`width 100%`) what you can do is the following - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/jsdNh/1/):

```
.outer{ background:yellow; position:absolute; width:80%; height:80px; margin:0 10%; padding: 0 11px}
.inner{ background:red; height:80px;}
```

Comment: Why the inner one have not set the "width:100%",it can still fill full of the father container,because of the father's absolute position?

Comment: because it's a non-floated, non-positioned(except relative) BLOCK-LEVEL element. Please read this [article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel) to better understand the box model concept. So by default..a DIV with default styling..it'll expand to fit it's parent.

Comment: Also, as stated in the article: _For static (non-positioned) elements, and relatively positioned elements where the width property has the value auto, the computed width will be the width of the containing block minus any horizontal margins, borders, padding, and scrollbars_ which means you can remove the padding from the outer DIV and place the margin back on the inner DIV in the above example!

Comment: Thank you with your patience，I get it:)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position: absolute;` (or changing it to `relative`) and `width: 100%;` from `.inner` will give you exactly what you want. Then, if you really need an element with `position: absolute;` inside, put it in `.inner`.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsdNh/2/)